# Ecore XMI to OMG standard convertion

Tags: java, xmi, ecore

We are trying to convert Ecore XMI file to OMG standard XMI.

Is there any API:s or tools which can be used to do this conversion?

Comment: Or is der any uml tool which can read ecore xmi file?

Answer (score 2):

In the editor you can use *Save As* and specify `.emof` as the file extension.  This will serialize the Ecore model as OMG-compliant EMOF.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply..I am able to convertto emof file...